# How to scroll to specific Cell (determined by its label) in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, scroll

i wanted to know if its possible to scroll to a specific Cell (determined by the Cell's label and not by the cell's rowindex) in an UITableView?

I need this cause my data is loaded on the fly and i don't know the cell's row index.

For example: I have a UITableView with a variable amount of rows and in each row there is a label for a name. Now i want to scroll to a specific name, but have the problem that I don't know the rowindex for this.

Is there any solution?

Thx in advance!

Comment: You should always use MVC aproach for tables. Don't use cells as data holders - even if they're created on-the-fly the data they show sholud be referenced from a more reliable source (the `model`). This way you'll also be able to 'calculate' indexpath of the cell you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search in your data sourceArray for the name, get the index of the object and construct the index path.

```
 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourRow inSection:yourSection];
```

If you have multiple sections you also have to find the section.